# Is it possible to make an ionic android application that can run functions even when app is closed?

Tags: android, ionic6, pedometer

I built an ionic android app that utilizes the cordova background mode and pedometer plugins to have the app running in the background. I have heard recently of pedometer apps that continue to count steps even when the app is closed. This contradicts what I know of android closing background apps for battery optimization. Do these pedometer apps that still run when closed really exist and if so how are they accomplishing this?

Comment: yes .. you need make plugin (Background service) and call it in ionic using javascript bridge    see this link for more details https://medium.com/@Codeible/understanding-and-using-services-in-android-background-foreground-services-8130f6bbf2a5#:~:text=A%20Background%20Service%20is%20a,bound%20to%20is%20still%20active.   https://medium.com/@sangkhim/build-your-first-cordova-plugin-for-ionic-native-38d29a170145